# Merge files to directories based on match of filename to directory name

Tags: linux, bash

I am pretty new to scripting so please be easy. I am aware that there is another forum that is related to this but does not exactly cover my issue.

I have a directory containing files and another directory containing the corresponding folders that I need to move each file to. Each file corresponds to the destination directory like:

DS-123.txt
/DS-123_alotofstuffhere/

I would like to automate the move based on a match of the first 6 characters of the filename to the first 6 of the directory.

I have this:

```
filesdir=$(ls ~/myfilesarehere/)
dir=$(ls ~/thedirectoriesareinthisfolder/)
for i in $filesdir; do
    for j in $dir; do
        if [[${i:6} == ${j:6}]]; then
                cp $i $j
        fi
    done
done
```

But when I run the script, I get the following error:

```
es: line 6: [[_DS-123_morefilenametext.fasta: command not found
```

I am using Linux (not sure what version on the supercomputer, sorry).

Comment: "I have this". Please describe what issues you are having with your code and ask a *specific* question related to that.

Comment: You need a space after `[[` and before `]]`.  `if [[ ${i:6} == ${j:6} ]]; then`

Comment: Please see my answer below.  I have tested it and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to use arrays and globbing to hold the list of files and directories, instead of `ls`.  With that change and a correction to the `[[ ... ]]` part, you code us this:

```
files=(~/myfilesarehere/*)
dirs=(~/thedirectoriesareinthisfolder/*)
for i in "${files[@]}"; do
  [[ -f "$i" ]] || continue          # skip if not a regular file
  for j in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    [[ -d "$j" ]] || continue        # skip if not a directory
    ii="${i##*/}" # get the basename of file
    jj="${j##*/}" # get the basename of dir
    if [[ ${ii:0:6} == ${jj:0:6} ]]; then
      cp "$i" "$j"
      # need to break unless a file has more than one destination directory
    fi
  done
done
```

`[[ -d "$j" ]]` check is necessary because your `dirs` array could contain some files too. To be safer, I have added a check for `$i` being a file as well.

---

Here is the solution that doesn't use arrays, as suggested by @triplee:

```
for i in ~/myfilesarehere/*; do
  [[ -f "$i" ]] || continue          # skip if not a regular file
  for j in ~/thedirectoriesareinthisfolder/*; do
    [[ -d "$j" ]] || continue        # skip if not a directory
    ii="${i##*/}" # get the basename of file
    jj="${j##*/}" # get the basename of dir
    if [[ ${ii:0:6} == ${jj:0:6} ]]; then
      cp "$i" "$j"
      # need to break unless a file has more than one destination directory
    fi
  done
done
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked! (perfect addition to get the base name of the file)

Comment: If you are happy with the solution, you could accept the answer. [What to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The first array doesn't seem to serve any useful purpose, though. You could simply do `for i in ~/myfilesarehere/*` instead.

Comment: Similarly, the loop over directories doesn't really need to have those in a variable, though it might improve performance ever so slightly.  To list only directories, you can do `~/thedirectoriesareinthisfolder/*/.`

Comment: Good comment, @tripleee - added an array-less solution to the answer.